# For loop error in Blackjack game

Tags: loops, for-loop

Can someone please explain to me why I am getting an error on line 20?

```
package play;
```

import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Deck 
{
    private int cardsInDeck;        //number of cards left in the deck
    private Card[] deck;            //the cards that are in the deck
    private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

```
public Deck()
{
    deck = new Card[52];        //52 cards in a deck
    int cardsUsed = 0;

    for(int s = 0; s < 4; s++); //suit of card
    {
        for(int n = 1; n <= 13; n++)        //number of card
        {
            deck[cardsUsed] = new Card(n, s);   **error is "s" on this line**

            cardsUsed++;
        }   
    }
    cardsInDeck = 0;
}

public void shuffle()
{
    for(int shuff = 51; shuff > 0; shuff--)
    {
        //select random # between 0 and 51
        int second = random.nextInt(52);

        //swap current card with new random card
        Card temp = deck[shuff];
        deck[shuff] = deck[second];
        deck[second] = temp;

    }
    cardsInDeck = 0;
}

public int remainingCards()
{
    //number of cards decrease as they are dealt. 
    return 52 - cardsInDeck;
}

public Card dealCard()
{
    //deals a card from the deck
    if(cardsInDeck == 52)
        shuffle();
    cardsInDeck++;
    return deck[cardsInDeck - 1];
}
```

}//end class Deck

Answer (score 0):

Look closer

```
for(int s = 0; s < 4; s++); //suit of card
{
    ...
}
```

This semicolon causes that the variable `s` to not declared in the block below, that's why the error happens a few lines below.